# Make two tables with same width

Tags: android, android-layout

In my `RelativeLayout`, I have an image and two tables, side by side.
The image has a fixed width, and I'd like the tables to fill the remaining area, but with equal widths.

Currently, the first table width is equal to the widest textView inside it, and the second table fills the screen width.

How it looks now:

```
 _________
|         | +---------+ +-----------------+
|         | | Table 1 | |     Table 2     |
|  Image  | +---------+ +-----------------+
|         | |         | |                 |
|_________| +---------+ +-----------------+
```

How I want it to look:

```
 _________
|         | +-------------+ +-------------+
|         | |   Table 1   | |   Table 2   |
|  Image  | +-------------+ +-------------+
|         | |             | |             |
|_________| +-------------+ +-------------+
```

Edit: I know I should use a GridView instead of tables, but I need to support API 9.

XML on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/3dyQHp3A).

Comment: Could you please post the XML layout code you currently have ?

Comment: use `weight` on the two tables, with even weighting.

Comment: @Br0therzS0ul check post update.
@ Doomsknight changing weight have no effect since they are on different tables.

Comment: @Guilherme I am not reffering to the weights of the textview, but the weights of the tables themselves..

Comment: Oops, I read labels instead of tables. But as I said in another answer, apparently I can't set weighs in `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Guilherme Answer posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo:

```
<LinearLayout
    width="match_parent"
    heigth="match_parent" 
    orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        width="50px"
        heigth="50px" />

    <TableLayout 
        width="0dp"
        heigth="match_parent"
        weigth="1" />

    <TableLayout 
        width="0dp"
        heigth="match_parent"
        weigth="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't set the weight if it belongs to a `RelativeLayout`. Is there another way to do that or I'll have to convert it to a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @Guilherme You can put LinearLayouts inside RelativeLayouts.

Comment: Hmm... and I suppose I must include just the tables in this `LinearLayout`. I'm trying this right now.

Comment: If possible, replace your `RelativeLayout` with a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @DroidBender I don't want to because there are other elements I'll place and will be easier with the Relative. Unless you could give me some other good reason, I'm just starting with Android.

Comment: @Br0therzS0ul I understand that, but I won't arrange all my elements in-line. That is why I opted for the Relative. Otherwise I'd probably need to add lots of inner Layouts to match the design I need. I'd rather keep the XML clean (or at least try to).

Comment: @Guilherme If you wrapped the two tables together only, you could probably achieve the design you want, while everything else is relative. But its up to you. Plenty of options, play around with them :) Peace out.

Answer (score 3):

Set the width to `0dp` and weight to `1` for each table.

So they are evenly distributed between the remaining space.

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: As you appear to be using a relative layout, you will need to wrap the two tables together in a `LinearLayout` first.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you can use a RelativeLayout but for the tables you want to have the same width, you'll have to use a nested LinearLayout in order to be able to set their weight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
       android:text="Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/nestedLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView">

    <TableLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
       android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:textSize="14dp"
           android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:text="999999"
           android:id="@+id/textView3"
           android:gravity="center" />

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tableLayout"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tableLayout"
       android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
           android:id="@+id/textView4"
           android:textSize="14dp"
           android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:text="999999"
           android:id="@+id/textView5"
           android:gravity="center" />
    </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```